# Combining different matrices in a for loop

Tags: r, binding, for-loop

I want to create different matrices in a loop and then combine (either cbind or rbind) them. But the following codes doesn't work. Why not? And how to fix it?

```
dependent = matrix(c(30,184,6,106), 2, 2, byrow=T)
independent = c(160,166)
expected = numeric()
{for(i in 1:length(independent))
a = dependent*independent[i]/sum(independent)
expected = cbind(expected,a)}
```

This gives:

```
expected
        [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 15.276074 93.69325
[2,]  3.055215 53.97546
```

This is the result of only using the final iteration of the for loop. So the result is like only 166 is used, but 160 isn't.

Comment: Circle 2 of 'The R Inferno' http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf tells why this is not a good approach to building your matrix, and gives some alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few comments:

1. Your `for` loop brackets are in the wrong place. You have:

   ```
   R> {for(i in 1:3) 
   +   cat(i, "\n")
   +   cat(i, "\n")
   + }
   1 
   2 
   3 
   3
   ```

   instead you should have:

   ```
   R> for(i in 1:3) {
   +   cat(i, "\n")
   +   cat(i, "\n")
   + }
   1 
   1 
   2 
   2 
   3 
   3
   ```

   When you construct a `for` loop and ommit the brackets, only the first line after the `for` statement is used.
2. You can make your `for` loop more efficient by saving the result of `sum(independent)` since that doesn't change with each iteration, i.e.

   ```
     for(i in 1:length(independent)){
         a = dependent*independent[i]
         expected = cbind(expected,a)
      }
      expected  = expected//sum(independent)
   ```
3. In fact you can vectorise the whole calculation

   ```
   y = sapply(independent, '*', dependent)
   matrix(y, ncol=4,nrow=2)/sum(independent)
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You could forgo the for loop altogether and use:

```
X <- lapply(independent, function(x) (dependent*x)/sum(independent))
do.call("cbind", X)
```

EDIT: I edited my response as the order was not correct.